# Kafka streams GlobalKTable throws Deserialization exception on Tombstone - null value- records

Tags: java, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I have a Spring cloud stream based Kafka Streams application where I'm binding a Global KTable to a Compact topic. When I push a Tombstone record to the topic (Non-empty key with null value) - my Kafka streams application fails with Deserialization exception. The failure is because my deserializer does not handle null records.

From the documentation, I thought GlobalKTable will not even "see" null-value records. Is it not the case? Do I need to handle null records in the deserializer?

```html
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Unable to deserialize
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument "src" is null
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._assertNotNull(ObjectMapper.java:4693)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3511)
    at common.domain.serdes.MySerde$MyDeserializer.deserialize(MySerde.java:47)
    at common.domain.serdes.MySerde$MyDeserializer.deserialize(MySerde.java:39)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.deserializeValue(SourceNode.java:63)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordDeserializer.deserialize(RecordDeserializer.java:66)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.GlobalStateUpdateTask.update(GlobalStateUpdateTask.java:91)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.GlobalStreamThread$StateConsumer.pollAndUpdate(GlobalStreamThread.java:240)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.GlobalStreamThread.run(GlobalStreamThread.java:289)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes; you have to check for `null` and return `null`. See any of the standard deserializers.

Unlike the `KafkaConsumer` 's `Fetcher` (which checks for `null` before calling), the `kafka-streams` calls it unconditionally. See

```
 at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.deserializeValue(SourceNode.java:63)
```

Comment: Thanks. Saw that and fixed my deserializer.